# Cloud Front gives Access Denied Error for Newly Uploaded files in S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

We upload some files to a S3 bucket via API. Some of these files have long file names. For an example 565ef0c5eb38f81511ff2503_565ef0c3eb38f81511ff24ff.png If we access the url of these files via Cloud Front, it gives a error for few mins. Later error goes off and files can be loaded. If we shorten the file name, it appears as soon as we upload it. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like negative caching of the s3 error.  I would lower the minimum TTL from the default of 5 minutes.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/HTTPStatusCodes.html#HTTPStatusCodes-no-custom-error-pages

> For the duration of the error caching minimum TTL (five minutes by default), CloudFront responds to subsequent viewer requests for the same object with the cached 4xx or 5xx status code.